# Как заставить работать вместе Vue CLI и OpenServer?

Tags: vue.js, openserver, vue-cli

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. У меня есть локальный сервер на OpenServer, с его помощью я могу работать с PHP. Но мне нужно сделать приложение на Vue CLI + PHP. К сожалению я не знаю как заставить все это работать вместе, мне нужно делать запросы в PHP, но Vue CLI и OpenServer запускаются на отдельных серверах. Пожалуйста, помогите

Comment: CСапое простое єто использовать laravel, тогда сам ларавель будут отвечать за пых, а вью бедет фронтом.
Либо вариант запуска как вы хотите, но тогда в настройках апи на пхп, нужно открыть крос запросы, т.к. они будут заблокированы. Сам долго мучался. Т.к. вью полюбому поднимит новый сервер который будет воспринят как сторонний.

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо, чтобы сервер PHP отдавал html страницу, к которой бы был подключен js-файл, который будет сбилден VUE, в дев режиме. По дефолту, если не ошибаюсь, путь такой: `localhost:8080/app.js`

Проблема с которой Вы столкнетесь - это hot-reload. Его не будет. Нужно будет что-то решать. По идее, должен помочь BrowserSync